# How to use monitor mode without losing Internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am using Kali whenever I turn my wireless card into monitor mode I lose connection with the Internet. Can I keep connection with the Internet while using monitor mode? Is there away to bind two modes (monitor & managed) into one wireless card?

My wireless card is Alfa AC1200 with two antennas and it supports monitor and packet injection... Please, any help

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

after that I lost internet connection

Answer (score 1):

When you are connected to WiFi, your card runs in managed mode. When you switch to monitor mode you start passively and not actively treating signals and hence you lose the connection.

Not every NIC supports both managed & monitor modes, but most of the Atheros chips do.

Comment: Yes, my card is Realtek not atheros. Could you please told me which model of alfa card should I buy?

Comment: I find this atheros card if this works both manage and monitor then please told me because I goona buy it from amazon (Alfa AWUS036NHA)

Comment: Please refer to https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Wireless_adapters/Chipset_table and https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Ath9k_htc

Comment: Check the tables before buying it off Amazon.

Comment: AFAIK, Alfa wireless adapters are also known to work well, check this article https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/buy-best-wireless-network-adapter-for-wi-fi-hacking-2019-0178550/ for more information if you want to get a ALFA wireless adapter.

Comment: I want to say that I bought the Alfa card AWUS036ACH which is mentioned in Null BYTE article but as I mentioned before when I went to monitor I lost Internet connection. I searched a lot and I find that this alfa card (AWUS036NHA) is recommended highly and it supports monitor and managed mode I am going to purchase it from amazon it costs 37$ dollar. I bought the Alfa (AWUS036NHA) with 59$ and it worth nothing ...

Comment: Thank you you helped me so much. Now I can purchase a card with confident wikidevi sites learns me lots ... Thanks again BRO.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Let me know how it goes, since the card has some bad reviews about not working properly or having bad reach. If I've helped please select my answer as the corect answer by clicking the checkbox.

Comment: *checkmark, not checkbox, my bad..

Comment: For those wondering why noone fixed the dead links for you, there you go ;-) : https://deviwiki.com/wiki/Wireless_adapters/Chipset_table and https://deviwiki.com/wiki/Category:Linux_driver/802dot11 would be your first stop

Answer (score 0):

by the way I find someone with the same problem as mine and someone suggest this to help him (Possibly because you need to configure differently your WiFi card: To do monitor mode and STA mode (AP client) at the same time, you need to bind two virtual interfaces (STA and monitor) to one physical interface (your wifi card).

I suggest you to try doing this by hand, before running wireshark. You will need to use the "iw" tool in order to do this.

Gave a look here (chapter "Adding interfaces with iw") http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw)  he meant to bind two modes (manage & monitor) in one card but how can someone do that I did not understand

Answer (score -1):

Monitor mode sets your adapter to "receive-only mode", which means that you cannot send any more requests to the internet. Wireless adapters can either send or receive packets but not both at the same time.

You can resort to using two WiFi adapters, one for monitor mode and the other one for managed mode.

Comment: I did that. one card set to manage and the second set to monitor but when I try to use the card which is in monitor mode with bettercap  it doesn't detect any device just detect the alfa card itself.... when I turn the card into manage mode it detects all the devices but it doesn't capture traffic and so is ettercap

Comment: Packet injection capability is how you send in monitor mode...